# Emacs shell-mode: Prevent RET sending input from anywhere

Tags: emacs, comint-mode

As the documentation says that RET will `comint-send-input` anywhere in a shell mode. The issue is that if you by mistake hit enter on any line and you are not at a prompt it will execute the whole random text until the next prompt. How can I prevent this from happening? It would be nice if hitting `Enter` anywhere out of the prompt will send you to a new prompt at the bottom.

Comment: Can you make use of C-h v comint-input-filter-functions ?

Comment: @aartis Idk, do you have ideas?

Comment: Nope, I happen to see that it could be useful in this context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```el
(defun my-comint-send-input-maybe ()
  "Only `comint-send-input' when point is after the latest prompt.

Otherwise move to the end of the buffer."
  (interactive)
  (let ((proc (get-buffer-process (current-buffer))))
    (if (and proc (>= (point) (marker-position (process-mark proc))))
        (comint-send-input)
      (goto-char (point-max)))))

(with-eval-after-load "comint"
  (define-key shell-mode-map [remap comint-send-input] 'my-comint-send-input-maybe))
```

You could replace `(goto-char (point-max))` with `(comint-copy-old-input)` to *insert* but not *send* the old input at the new prompt; but that's still liable to cause problems when the inserted input looks like output.

However, also note the comments and link in <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `comint-send-input` regarding `comint-get-old-input` -- this can be used to implement custom logic for establishing what the "old input" should be when `comint-send-input` is invoked with point before the process mark.

Comment: This works like a charm. Thank you. I did make a replacement to `comint-get-old-input`, it is much more convenient. If by mistake I hit `RET` I can easily delete it, if I want execute some previous input I am able to do that.

Comment: I was just thinking, how can I test if current line is output of some command or an old prompt. Because even better could be this logic `(if (command output) (goto-char (point-max)) (comint-send-input))`.

Comment: I guess the key thing is that you'd need to differentiate the point between the end of a command and the beginning of the resulting output (if any).  I don't know offhand whether that's currently supported.  If not, you'd need to track those positions yourself.

Comment: `M-x apropos RET comint-last RET` would be of interest, but you'd need to read the code to confirm how those variables are used and when they're reliably available.

Comment: @phils, see my take on this.

Answer (score 1):

Bulletproof:

```
(defun comint-send-input-or-insert-previous-input ()
  "Call `comint-send-input' if point is after the process output marker.
Otherwise, move point to the process mark and try to insert a previous input
from `comint-input-ring' (if any) returned by `comint-previous-input-string'
and affected by the current value of `comint-input-ring-index'.

Implementation is synthesized from and inspired by the `comint-after-pmark-p',
`comint-goto-process-mark', and `comint-copy-old-input' functions."
  (interactive)
  (let ((process (get-buffer-process (current-buffer))))
    (if (not process)
        (user-error "Current buffer has no process")
      (let ((pmark (process-mark process)))
        (if (<= (marker-position pmark) (point))
            (comint-send-input)
          (goto-char pmark)
          (when (and (eolp) comint-input-ring)
            (let ((input (comint-previous-input-string 0)))
              (when (char-or-string-p input)
                (insert input)))))))))
```